# Replacing non frequent elements in sequencial c#

Tags: c#, linq, replace, sequence

I have an array that contains integers

```
1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,4,4,4,4
```

I want to be able to replace  elements that don't complete the repeated order of the sequence so from the example above it would be like

```
1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4.
```

I have tried playing around with a few ugly sprawling functions but I am like looping through but it was all in vein so am.

wondering if there is a neat LINQ- way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if the original sequence is _1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,2,4,4,4,5,5,4,4_ This could escalate to a very complex problem

Comment: In addition to @Steve comment, what if the input is 1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,2,4,4,4,**1**,5,5,4,4 ?

Comment: @shay__ the bold 1 would become 4.

Comment: @Miro Bels Could you edit the question and describe the problem with string extraction more thoroughly. Explain which part of string you want to compare or the whole. Also include more test examples and the code you are using currently and maybe adapt it for testing if you are pulling strings from internet to include them in array.

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard if not impossible to implement this in just only LINQ. You would have to implement the following method if you would like to have functionallity like the one you described:

```
using System;

namespace LinqSequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arr = new int[]
            {
                1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,2,4,4,4,5,5,4,4
            };
            var newArr = SequenceReplace(arr);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",newArr));
            //OUT: 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5
        }
        static int[] SequenceReplace(int[] arr) 
        {
            int length = arr.Length;
            var newArr = new int[length];
            int previous = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (newArr[previous] > arr[i]) 
                {
                    newArr[i] = newArr[previous];
                }
                else
                {
                    newArr[i] = arr[i];
                }
                previous = i;
            }
            return newArr;
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

The previous program was not correct because it didn't look at both adjectant fields. So the program didn't work for the test case in your question. So this is the new answer. It looks at both adjectant fields and if current is diffrent than both it replaces current with the one on the left. Also it takes care of edge cases. If the length is less than 2 it just returns that array, if length is 2 it returns array with 2 element 0's. If there is no next element it replaces that element with the previous one.

```
using System;

namespace LinqSequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arr1 = new int[]
            {
                1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,4,4,4,4
            };

            var newArr1 = SequenceReplace(arr1);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",newArr1));
            //OUT: 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4

            var arr2 = new int[]
            {
                1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,2,4,4,4,5,5,4,4
            };
            var newArr2 = SequenceReplace(arr2);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",newArr2));
            //OUT: 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,4,4
        }
        static int[] SequenceReplace(int[] arr) 
        { 
            int length = arr.Length;
            if (length == 2) return new int[] { arr[0], arr[0] };
            else if (length < 2) return arr;
            var newArr = new int[length];
            newArr[0] = arr[0];
            int previous = 0, next = 2;

            for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
            {
                if ((next < length &&
                    newArr[previous] != arr[i] && 
                    arr[next] != arr[i]) ||
                    next >= length)
                {
                    newArr[i] = newArr[previous];
                }
                else
                {
                    newArr[i] = arr[i];
                }
                previous++;
                next++;
            }
            return newArr;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's [ideone](http://ideone.com/QPQGFs).

Comment: Why are you using replacement when the user just want to change the order?  My solution is better.

Comment: @jdweng It's not about the order if you look carefully at the question, it's about the sequence where you replace an element if it doesn't comply (is less than the current number of sequence) with the sequence of increasing numbers with the previous known number in sequence.

Comment: @jdweng Did you at least look at OP's expected output for the input he gave?  There are not 5 1's in the input as there are in the output. This is not sorting but I don't know what else to tell you to convince you. Also my comment was from previous answer and not from the edit I posted next. So look at the updated answer where it is clearer.

Comment: @jdweng Look at the included ideone example above and check out the generic method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31638548/4965962).

Comment: I'v3 been looking at Mirro's updated comment.  Looks like he is trying to sort an alpha-numeric string. : 
 
  flag  
 
thank you. but the problem i am having is that i have to cut those numbers off a string and compare them. like 00H1,00H1,00H2,00H1,00H1,00H2,00H2,00H2,00H3,00H3,00H2,00H3. WHAT I NEED IS look for those that dont fit in the sequence like 00H2 in this case wont much the number between it like 00H1,00H2,00H1. so i replace 00H2 with 00H1 then move on to the next.. thanx

Comment: @jdweng I still don't think this is a sorting problem. Maybe I don't get it because there is just one example of input and expected output. It still looks like he wants to compare adjectant fields and if current is diffrent than both replace it with the one on the left.

Answer (score -1):

Just use orderBy func like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { //your data };
list = list.OrderBy(i=> i);
```

Comment: What if he got the numbers like "1 1 2 1 5 5 4 4"? And he wants the result to be "1 1 1 1 5 5 4 4" then ordering it won't solve the issue.

Comment: It is not a problem of ordering anything but replacing an out of order number with the current number

Comment: thank you. but the problem i am having is that i have to cut those numbers off a string and compare them. like 00H1,00H1,00H2,00H1,00H1,00H2,00H2,00H2,00H3,00H3,00H2,00H3. WHAT I NEED IS look for those that dont fit in the sequence like 00H2 in this case wont much the number between it like 00H1,00H2,00H1. so i replace 00H2 with 00H1 then move on to the next.. thanx

Answer (score -1):

Use sort and regex like this

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "00H1,00H1,00H2,00H1,00H1,00H2,00H2,00H2,00H3,00H3,00H2,00H3";
            List<string> array = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
            array.Sort((x,y) => GetSuffix(x).CompareTo(GetSuffix(y)));
            string output = string.Join(",",array);


        }
        static int GetSuffix(string input)
        {
            string pattern = "H(?'suffix'\\d*)";
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            return int.Parse(match.Groups["suffix"].Value);
        }​
```

Here is Linq solution

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "00H1,00H1,00H2,00H1,00H1,00H2,00H2,00H2,00H3,00H3,00H2,00H3";
            List<string> array = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();

            array = array.Select(x => new
            {
                suffix = GetSuffix(x),
                item = x
            }).OrderBy(x => x.suffix).Select(x => x.item).ToList();

            string output = string.Join(",",array);


        }
        static int GetSuffix(string input)
        {
            string pattern = "H(?'suffix'\\d*)";
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            return int.Parse(match.Groups["suffix"].Value);
        }​
```

Comment: Why did somebody grade this as -1?  Good solution.